# how to split strings in dataframe using pandas_udf in pyspark

Tags: string, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a `dataframe` of one column only. I would like to split the string using the `pandas_udf` in `pyspark`. Hence, I have the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

@pandas_udf('str')
def split_msg(string):
  msg_ = string.split(" ")
  return msg_

temp = temp.select("_c6").withColumn("decoded", 
split_msg(temp._c6)).drop("_c6")
```

But this is not working.

any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your function to the following:

```
@pandas_udf('array<string>', PandasUDFType.SCALAR) 
def split_msg(string): 
    msg_ = string.str.split(" ") 
    return msg_
```

basically, your function returnType should be array of StringType() and the argument `string` should be a Series and thus you will need `string.str.split(" ")`

However, if you just want to split the text, Spark's DataFrame API provides a built-in function, [pyspark.sql.functions.split](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) which should be more efficient than using a pandas_udf