# Apply wordninja.split() using pandas_udf

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, split, user-defined-functions, pandas-udf

I have a dataframe `df` with the column `sld` of type string which includes some consecutive characters with no space/delimiter. One of the libraries that can be used to split is wordninja:

E.g. `wordninja.split('culturetosuccess')` outputs `['culture','to','success']`

Using `pandas_udf`, I have:

```py
@pandas_udf(ArrayType(StringType()))
def split_word(x):
   splitted = wordninja.split(x)
   return splitted
```

However, it throws an error when I apply it on the column `sld`:

```py
df1=df.withColumn('test', split_word(col('sld')))
```

> typeerror: expected string or bytes-like object

What I tried:

I noticed that there is a similar problem with the well-known function `split()`, but the workaround is to use `string.str` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58221294/how-to-split-strings-in-dataframe-using-pandas-udf-in-pyspark). This doesn't work on `wordninja.split`.

Any work around this issue?

Edit: I think in a nutshell the issue is:
the `pandas_udf` input is `pd.series` while `wordninja.split` expects string.

My df looks like this:

```
+-------------+
|sld          |
+-------------+
|"hellofriend"|
|"restinpeace"|
|"this"       |
|"that"       |
+-------------+
```

I want something like this:

```
+-------------+---------------------+
|    sld      |         test        |
+-------------+---------------------+
|"hellofriend"|["hello","friend"]   |
|"restinpeace"|["rest","in","peace"]|
|"this"       |["this"]             |
|"that"       |["that"]             |
+-------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.apply` to perform computation on each element of the Pandas series, something like this:

```py
@pandas_udf(ArrayType(StringType()))
def split_word(x: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
   splitted = x.apply(lambda s: wordninja.split(s))
   return splitted
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is using `udf`.

```py
import wordninja
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([("hellofriend",), ("restinpeace",), ("this",), ("that",)], ['sld'])

@F.udf
def split_word(x):
   return wordninja.split(x)

df.withColumn('col2', split_word('sld')).show()
# +-----------+-----------------+
# |        sld|             col2|
# +-----------+-----------------+
# |hellofriend|  [hello, friend]|
# |restinpeace|[rest, in, peace]|
# |       this|           [this]|
# |       that|           [that]|
# +-----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have tried udf but it is really slow!
it goes like row by row :(